# Updating yum repo in RHEL 7 with Ansible

Tags: rhel, yum, ansible

I have been trying to write a playbook that adds the EPEL repo to the list of repos available.

The `playbook` I have is:

```
- hosts: all

  # define variables.
  vars:
    epelReleaseMajorVersion: 7
    epelReleaseMinorVersion: 8

  tasks:
    - name: add epel repo
      yum-repository:
        name: add epel repo
        description: EPEL YUM repo
        baseurl:  http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/$epelReleaseMajorVersion/x86_64/e/epel-release-$epelReleaseMajorVersion-$epelReleaseMinorVersion.noarch.rpm
        tags: addEpelRepo
```

I am trying to run this `playbook` like so:
`ansible-playbook -v -i "localhost," -c local serverSetup.yml`

and get the following error:

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/root/ansible/playbooks/serverSetup.yml': line 21, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
    - name: add epel repo
      ^ here
```

My questions:
1. Am I using the variables epelReleaseMajorVersion etc. correctly?
2. How do I solve for this error? I have been taking a look at the docs but there do not seem to be many examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to the [Ansible yum_repository_module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_repository_module.html)

Your code should be

```
- hosts: all

  # define variables.
  vars:
    epelReleaseMajorVersion: 7
    epelReleaseMinorVersion: 8

  tasks:
    - name: add epel repo
      yum_repository:
        name: epel_repo
        description: EPEL YUM repo
        baseurl:  http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/{{epelReleaseMajorVersion}}/x86_64/
```

So you misspelled the name of the module. Baseurl was wrong. Variable reference was wrong. And `yum_repository` ansible module does not have any parameter called `tags`